# Map Post Parameter With Dash to Model In Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following property that I need mapped to a post parameter in Spring.  Is there an attribute I can use?  It accepts application/x-www-form-urlencoded for string-based payloads, multipart/form-data for binary payloads.  Other properties are mapping fine without underscores.

```
String deliveryAttemptId;
```

mapped to the post parameter

```
DELIVERY-ATTEMPT-ID
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/notifications")
public class NotificationController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public void grade(EventNotificationRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {        

    }
```

**Model**

```
public class EventNotificationRequest {

    String deliveryAttemptId;
```

Comment: Please clarify whether this endpoint is a web service endpoint or a form-processing endpoint. The approach is different depending on the answer.

Comment: MVC Controller for spring

Comment: That part I got (i.e., that there's a Spring Web MVC controller processing the request). My question is whether you have an HTML form submitting the data, or whether it's a web service client.

Comment: Either one can make a POST, application/x-www-form-urlencoded for string-based payloads, multipart/form-data for binary payloads

Comment: Isnt there a way to map it like I posted here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646634/map-json-property-with-period-to-class-property-in-spring-controller

Comment: So we understand eachother: you want to make a post request like `host.com/context/notifications?DELIVERY_ATTEMPT_ID=someValue` and have it mapped to a property of a class (`EventNotificationRequest`)?

Comment: Yep exactly how do I do that

Comment: <input name="DELIVERY-ATTEMPT-ID" value="Delivery1" size="50"/>

Comment: There may not be a way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943878/how-to-map-a-b-query-to-a-command-object-in-spring-mvc

Comment: In my case I just needed https://stackoverflow.com/q/23892179/733092.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a work around for this Spring limitation.  This also fixes case sensitivity issues with parameters.  Sorry I am used to .NET and how easy binding is so it's frustrating to run into these Spring issues.

[HttpServletRequest parameter lowecase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969170/httpservletrequest-parameter-lowecase)

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/grade")
        @ResponseBody
        public void grade(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {  

            EventNotificationRequest notificationRequest = new LearningStudioEventNotificationRequest();
            notificationRequest.setDeliveryAttemptId(getCaseInsensitiveParameter(request, "DELIVERY-ATTEMPT-ID"));
```