# Spring, middle score in request parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, query-string

Is there a way to map a query parameter with a middle score using requests in spring?

I have no problem binding single worded parameters doing this:

Uri example: `http://localhost:8080/test/?product=hotels`

```
public class CitiesRequest{
    private ProductType product;

    public ProductType getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

But I'd like to be able to receive parameters like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/?product-type=hotels
```

Comment: I'm new to Spring, so I don't really know the inner workings or if what I'm doing is right.

As far as I can tell, the setter for the parameters need to be the same as the parameter name, so I tried changing it a few times like this:
`setProductType, setProduct_type, setProducttype`
but that didn't work.
I'm not really getting any error, the parameter just remains null.

Comment: What version of Spring and what kind of controller are you using ? For Spring > 3.1, the `@RequestMapping` annotation can provide explicitely the parameter name.

Comment: I'm using version 3.2.3, and I'm not sure what you mean about the controller, as I'm fairly new to this.

I'm aware of the `@RequestMapping` annotation, but since I'll be taking many parameters I'm trying to avoid it to keep the code a little cleaner. That's why I'm using the request instead of annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring maps the query parameter key to the name of the Java variable. However, it's syntactically incorrect to have a variable name with a hyphen in Java, which explains why  you're finding it particularly difficult to get Spring to set the parameter's value for you.

One workaround that *might* work is to just have a `Map<String, String[]>` parameter to represent **all** of the parameters. Then Spring doesn't have to map any query parameters to variable names, so the hyphenated name might end up in that map of all parameters. It may not be as comfortable as pre-split parameter objects, but it might get the hyphenated keys.

Another solution might be to configure the `WebDataBinder`, which controls how data from HTTP requests are mapped onto your controller's request parameters. But that's a whole can of worms, especially if you're just starting out with Spring. You can read more about it in the documentation under "data binding".

Answer (score 6):

As Misha stated it is syntactically incorrect to have a variable name with a hyphen in Java. But Spring is fine with that and allows you to specify a **parameter** name (in the request) different from the **variable** name (in java code). For exemple, when using `RequestMapping` driven controller, one can write :

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView getProduct(
        @RequestParam("product-type") String productType) {
...
}
```

That way, `getProduct` will be called for a url like `http://localhost/test?product-type=hotels` and the parameter `productType`will receive the value `hotels`. And all is still purely declarative.